# Silence PackageManager from an APK smali file

Tags: java, apk, dex, smali

Basically i want to remove the function of an app to check weather it was installed from PlayStore or other sources. What it does is if its installed elsewhere than Play Store-> print message and stuck on loading... its coded in SMALI, and i dont really undesrtand it, even tho i used jadx to peak, i cant edit in it. please if someone know how to silence the checker and keep proceeding witouth crashing the app or just have any idea let me know, thanks!

```
.class final Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "CheckEmulatorCommand.kt"

# interfaces
.implements Ljava/lang/Runnable;


# annotations
.annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/EnclosingMethod;
    value = Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;->a(Z)V
.end annotation

.annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/InnerClass;
    accessFlags = 0x18
    name = null
.end annotation


# instance fields
.field final synthetic a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;


# direct methods
.method constructor <init>(Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;)V
    .locals 0

    iput-object p1, p0, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;

    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method


# virtual methods
.method public final run()V
    .locals 9

    .line 1
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;

    iget-object v0, v0, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;->c()Landroid/app/Activity;

    move-result-object v0

    const v1, 0x7f12001e

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/app/Activity;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v0

    const-string v1, "activity.getString(R.string.STORE_PLACEHOLDER)"

    invoke-static {v0, v1}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/i;->d(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 2
    sget-object v1, Lf/a/a/e/k;->a:Lf/a/a/e/k;

    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;

    iget-object v2, v2, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;

    invoke-virtual {v2}, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;->c()Landroid/app/Activity;

    move-result-object v2

    invoke-virtual {v2}, Landroid/app/Activity;->getApplicationContext()Landroid/content/Context;

    move-result-object v2

    const-string v3, "activity.applicationContext"

    invoke-static {v2, v3}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/i;->d(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Lf/a/a/e/k;->a(Landroid/content/Context;)Z

    move-result v1

    const-string v2, "java.lang.String.format(format, *args)"

    const/4 v3, 0x0

    const/4 v4, 0x1

    if-eqz v1, :cond_0

    .line 3
    sget-object v1, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/m;->a:Lkotlin/jvm/internal/m;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;

    iget-object v1, v1, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;->c()Landroid/app/Activity;

    move-result-object v1

    const v5, 0x7f120056

    invoke-virtual {v1, v5}, Landroid/app/Activity;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    const-string v5, "activity.getString(R.str\u2026ge_NotInstalledFromStore)"

    invoke-static {v1, v5}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/i;->d(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    const/4 v5, 0x2

    new-array v6, v5, [Ljava/lang/Object;

    iget-object v7, p0, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;

    iget-object v7, v7, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;

    invoke-virtual {v7}, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;->c()Landroid/app/Activity;

    move-result-object v7

    const v8, 0x7f120009

    invoke-virtual {v7, v8}, Landroid/app/Activity;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v7

    aput-object v7, v6, v3

    aput-object v0, v6, v4

    invoke-static {v6, v5}, Ljava/util/Arrays;->copyOf([Ljava/lang/Object;I)[Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-static {v1, v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->format(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-static {v1, v2}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/i;->d(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    goto :goto_0

    .line 4
    :cond_0
    sget-object v1, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/m;->a:Lkotlin/jvm/internal/m;

    iget-object v1, p0, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;

    iget-object v1, v1, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;

    invoke-virtual {v1}, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;->c()Landroid/app/Activity;

    move-result-object v1

    const v5, 0x7f12005b

    invoke-virtual {v1, v5}, Landroid/app/Activity;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    const-string v5, "activity.getString(R.str\u2026essage_StoreNotInstalled)"

    invoke-static {v1, v5}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/i;->d(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    new-array v5, v4, [Ljava/lang/Object;

    aput-object v0, v5, v3

    invoke-static {v5, v4}, Ljava/util/Arrays;->copyOf([Ljava/lang/Object;I)[Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v3

    invoke-static {v1, v3}, Ljava/lang/String;->format(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-static {v1, v2}, Lkotlin/jvm/internal/i;->d(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 5
    :goto_0
    iget-object v2, p0, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;

    iget-object v2, v2, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a;->a:Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;

    invoke-virtual {v2}, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a;->c()Landroid/app/Activity;

    move-result-object v2

    new-instance v3, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b$a;

    invoke-direct {v3, p0, v0, v1}, Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b$a;-><init>(Lcom/casualino/base/commands/controllers/a$a$b;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Landroid/app/Activity;->runOnUiThread(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V

    return-void
.end method
```

Comment: Seems to be the same use with a different account and the identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72291627/modifying-smali-files-in-order-to-run-apk-on-my-phone

Comment: ive lost sleep the last 2 days! Whats the big deal if somebody can give a hand???

Comment: Sorry but reverse engineering requires a lot of time. But I still think that you are searching at the wrong point. Try to better understand the call hierarchy that lead to this method. If you still want to try you can simply skip sections by placing goto commands and matching labels. BTW: Why have you created a new account and then repost your old question nearly identical? That is always bad style and won't help you getting an answer. The number of people reading is already very small (your last post was viewed by may be 12 people).

Comment: The file i mentioned in this post is another from the one yasterday. Im getting closer to the truth, im just not familiar with .smali. Thanks for your help anyway!